# Web2py: Write SQL query: "SELECT x FROM y" using DAL, when x and y are variables, and convert the results to a list?

Tags: database, web2py

My action passes a list of values from a column `x` in table `y` to the view. How do I write the following SQL: `SELECT x FROM y`, using DAL "language", when `x` and `y` are variables given by the view. Here it is, using `exequtesql()`.

```
def myAction():
    x = request.args(0, cast=str)
    y = request.args(1, cast=str)
    myrows = db.executesql('SELECT '+ x + ' FROM '+ y)
    #Let's convert it to the list:
    mylist = []
    for row in myrows:
        value = row #this line doesn't work
        mylist.append(value)
    return (mylist=mylist)
```

Also, is there a more convenient way to convert that data to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that you must create table definitions for any tables you want to access (i.e., `db.define_table('mytable', ...)`). Assuming you have done that and that `y` is the name of a single table and `x` is the name of a single field in that table, you would do:

```
    myrows = db().select(db[y][x])
    mylist = [r[x] for r in myrows]
```

Note, if any records are returned, `.select()` always produces a `Row` object, which comprises a set of `Row` objects (even if only a single field was selected). So, to extract the individual values into a list, you have to iterate over the `Rows` object and extract the relevant field from each `Row` object. The above code does so via a list comprehension.

Also, you might want to add some code to check whether `db[y]` and `db[y][x]` exist.